# Merging same columns from a table with different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to retrieve data from one table but the data is based on conditions this is my query:

```
Select 
    Store_ID,
    (select Stc_Item_Desc, Imported_Date, Store_ID, Quantity_On_Hand
     from DailyStockHistory 
     where Stc_Item_Desc = 'SAWA/QuickNet prepaid triosim' 
       and Imported_Date = '3-15-2017' 
       and Store_ID like 'S%'),
    (select Stc_Item_Desc, Imported_Date, Store_ID, Quantity_On_Hand
     from DailyStockHistory 
     where Stc_Item_Desc = 'SAWA/QuickNet prepaid triosim' 
       and Imported_Date = '3-22-2017' 
       and Store_ID like 'S%')
from 
    DailyStockHistory
```

Any help please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can provide some sample data and sample of your expected data.

Comment: SAWA/QUICKnet prepaid TrioSIM 2017-03-15 SCCC387 518 SAWA/QUICKnet prepaid TrioSIM 2017-03-22 SCCC387 251 the data must me near each other

Comment: Just do a join against the same table

Comment: i just need someone to write it clearly so i can get it not only commands, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate `PIVOT` table to get your expected output, please check this.

Sample Data:

```
Insert Into DailyStockHistory Values('SCCC387','SAWA/QuickNet prepaid triosim','2017-03-15',518)
Insert Into DailyStockHistory Values('SCCC387','SAWA/QuickNet prepaid triosim','2017-03-22',251)
```

SQL:

```
Select 
    *
From 
(
    Select 
        Stc_Item_Desc, Imported_Date, Store_ID, Quantity_On_Hand 
    From DailyStockHistory
    Where Stc_Item_Desc = 'SAWA/QuickNet prepaid triosim' 
        And Store_ID Like 'S%' 
        And (Imported_Date = '3-15-2017' Or Imported_Date = '3-22-2017')
) AS Data
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Quantity_On_Hand)
    FOR Imported_Date IN ([3-15-2017],[3-22-2017])
) AS PIVOTData
```

Output:

[image]

`3-15-2017` & `3-22-2017` are columns for `Quantity_On_Hand` quantity according to `Imported_Date` date.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you combine conditions in one query instead of combining 2 query results:

```
Select Store_ID,
     (select Stc_Item_Desc, Imported_Date,Store_ID, Quantity_On_Hand
     from DailyStockHistory 
     where Stc_Item_Desc = 'SAWA/QuickNet prepaid triosim' AND
         ((Imported_Date = '3-15-2017') OR (Imported_Date = '3-22-2017'))
         AND Store_ID like 'S%'
      )
     from DailyStockHistory
```

To get `Quantity_On_Hand` for a given day you could simply do another query

```
     select Quantity_On_Hand
     from *above result*
     where Imported_Date = '3-15-2017'
```

Comment: Dear @Mhd cause i need the Quantity_On _Hand and its different in those dates and in addition to your answer when i excute the query this error appears "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS"

Comment: @ahmad look at the updated response. Since you are selecting `Imported_Date`, you can do group by and count on the date you want.

Comment: can you please guide me how to make it ?

Comment: i just need to merge those data in 1 query in such a way i will get 2 different quantity on hand of different dates in one row @Mhd

Comment: @ahmad What de you mean by "in one row"? you mean count(how many quantity on hand for each date)?

Comment: i mean two different quantities for the two dates but all in one row on the same row @Mhd

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    Stc_Item_Desc, Imported_Date, Store_ID, Quantity_On_Hand 
From 
    DailyStockHistory 
Where
    Stc_Item_Desc = 'SAWA/QuickNet prepaid triosim' 
    And Store_ID Like 'S%' 
    And (Imported_Date = '3-15-2017' Or Imported_Date = '3-22-2017)
```

Comment: buddy @MaCron i need the columns near each other not on different rows